# Bootstrap - Automatically scrolls down the page (Unwanted)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This never used to happen on my site, I haven't knowingly adjusted anything in the index which could cause the issue. But with the regular web address it automatically scrolls down the page. However if I type www.domain.uk/# it works as intended. 
Any ideas? Sorry for the noobie question :D

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: if you can post an example on jsfiddle.net if would be better

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask __ AFAIK there are no mind readers here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because you're modifying a Bootstrap template. Some templates have scrolling features that tend to be useless once you do any kind of customizing. I would go through the templates' Javascripts and look for anything that's related to scrolling, and either fix or remove it.